# PHP no ejecuta en el servidor

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto `HTML` con `PHP`  y mientras lo desarrollaba  en local andaba genial, una vez lo subí  al servidor se me han presentado varios inconvenientes,  por ejemplo:

tengo una pagina `"index-mercadeo.php"` que realiza una consulta por ajax para mostrar una tabla dinámica. sin embargo cuando subí la pagina al servidor , la tabla queda vacía, no tiene ningún error aparentemente.

les dejo el código 
->index-mercadeo.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
  header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location:index.php");
  echo"<script language='javascript'>window.location='index.php'</script>;";
   exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Mercadeo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Plugin CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FAVICON IMG -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favico.png">

    <!-- Elements AJAX -->
    <script src="js/obtener_ajax.js"></script>





  </head>

  <body id="page-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary fixed-top text-uppercase" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Sistema Inventario</a>
        <a href="do_logout.php" title="Salir"><img style="height: 60px; width: 60px;" src="img/salir-opcion.png"></a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
      <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px"></div>


    <!--  Section -->
    <section id="ubicacion.php">
      <div class="container">
       <span>"Usuario : <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"] ?>"</span><br><span>"Fecha: <?php echo date('d/m/Y') ?>"</span>
        <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px"></div>

                    <form  class="form-basic"  id="fcrear">

                      <div class="form-title-row">
                          <h1>Realizar Inventario</h1>
                      </div>
                <div class="container">

                 <div class="form-row">
                        <label class="control-label" style="padding: 10px">Canal</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <select name="canal"  onclick="obtenerRz(this.value)" onchange="obtenerRz(this.value)" required="true" >
                              <?php
                               include 'conexion.php';
                               $pdo = Database::connect();
                               $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT nom_canal FROM ubicacion";
                               foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                        echo '<option value="'. $row['nom_canal'] .'" >'. $row['nom_canal'] .'</option>';
                               }
                               Database::disconnect();
                              ?>
                         </select>  
                        </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-row">
                        <label class="control-label" style="padding: 10px">Razon Social</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <div id="error"></div>  
                          <div id="Rz"></div>
                        </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-row">
                        <label class="control-label" style="padding: 10px">Sucursal</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <div id="errorSc"></div>  
                          <div id="Sucursal"></div>
                        </div>
                  </div>

                 </form>

      </div>
    </section>

    <!--  SECCION  LISTA DE PRODUCTOS -->

     <!--  Section -->
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mb-0">Inventario</h2>
        <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px"></div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">

            <!-- TABLE-->
           <div id="errorProducto"></div>  
           <div id="Productos"></div>

          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </section>



    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="copyright py-4 text-center text-white">
      <div class="container">
        <img class="img-fluid mb-5 d-block mx-auto" src="img/footer-logo.png">
        <small>Copyright &copy; 2018 -  Todos los derechos reservados</small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button (Only visible on small and extra-small screen sizes) -->
    <div class="scroll-to-top d-lg-none position-fixed ">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger d-block text-center text-white rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </a>
    </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="js/freelancer.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

->optenerProductos.php [Donde se genera la tabla dinamica por ajax.]

```
<?php

    if (!empty($_GET['nom_canal']) && !empty($_GET['nom_rz']) && !empty($_GET['ide_sucursal'])) {
        $nom_canal = $_REQUEST['nom_canal'];
        $nom_rz = $_REQUEST['nom_rz'];
        $ide_sucursal = $_REQUEST['ide_sucursal'];
    }


?>
   <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate" action="actualizarInventario.php" method="post">
   <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th bgcolor="#f5f3f3">ID Ubicacion</th>
                  <th>Producto</th>
                  <th>ID Producto</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>Historico</th>
                  <th bgcolor="#f5f3f3">Inventario</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <?php
                       include 'conexion.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE estado_producto = 'ACTIVO' AND ide_canal = (SELECT ide_canal FROM ubicacion WHERE nom_canal = '".$nom_canal."' AND nom_rz = '".$nom_rz."' AND ide_sucursal = '".$ide_sucursal."' ) ";
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td bgcolor="#f5f3f3" >'. $row['ide_canal'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['nom_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['ide_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['estado_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['historico'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td><input  class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="0" name = "inventario[]" required="required" ></td>';
                                echo '<td><input type="hidden" value="'. $row['ide'] .'" name="ideProducto[]"></div></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }
                       Database::disconnect();
                 ?>
                 <div ></div>
              </tbody>
 </table>
 <br>
      <div id="success"></div>
      <div class="form-group" align="center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton">Enviar Reporte</button>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Aquí la muestra de como queda la pagina una vez llamo la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cabecera de la tabla se crea correctamente y como se ve en la imagen , el `<tbody>` cierra con `</tbody>`  por lo cual no sabría si es un error o que no ejecuta la consulta.

pero ya he probado la consulta en la BD y funciona.

Consulta BD:

```
<?php
                       include 'conexion.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE estado_producto = 'ACTIVO' AND ide_canal = (SELECT ide_canal FROM ubicacion WHERE nom_canal = '".$nom_canal."' AND nom_rz = '".$nom_rz."' AND ide_sucursal = '".$ide_sucursal."' ) ";
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td bgcolor="#f5f3f3" >'. $row['ide_canal'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['nom_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['ide_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['estado_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['historico'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td><input  class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="0" name = "inventario[]" required="required" ></td>';
                                echo '<td><input type="hidden" value="'. $row['ide'] .'" name="ideProducto[]"></div></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }
                       Database::disconnect();
                 ?>
```

Gracias.

**EDICIO**

Otras tablas si se crean dinamicamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa la ruta que estás usando en Ajax, es probable que tengas la ruta anterior (en local) y que la misma no concuerde con la ruta actual. En la pregunta dices que se debería llamar a `optenerProductos.php` pero en la imagen el formulario tiene otro archivo en el `action`, el cual se llama `actualizarInventario.php`.

Comment: Tiene pinta que una de las 3 variables que coges con el REQUEST no te la esta cogiendo bien y por consiguiente la consulta te la devuelve vacía y sin resultados (sin fallar la consulta), comprueba eso y a ver que te devuelven esos REQUEST.

Comment: Solo decir a parte de lo indicado por los compañeros que el código expuesto en la pregunta es **vulnerable a inyeccion SQL**: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Me suena a un problema de CORS, sin mencionar algunas malas pràcticas que estàs usando en PHP. Te darè un tip de PHP, usa sintaxis como esta:

<?php if(...) { ?>
còdigo html sin escapar
<?php } ?> 

Aplica para cualquier estructura de control.